# listen bottom tab bar press event in component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-native-webview

is it possible to listen to bottom tab bar press event in the component and perform some logic in that component

naviagtor.ts

```
<Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Cloud" screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
                tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: COLORS.primary }
            }}>
                <Tab.Screen name="Back"
                    options={{
                        tabBarItemStyle: styles.iconspacing,
                        tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => <Text style={[{ color: focused ? COLORS.light_green : COLORS.white }, styles.lable]}>Zurück</Text>,
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                            return (<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowLeft} color={focused ? COLORS.light_green : COLORS.white} size={20} />)
                        },
                    }} component={WebViewComponent} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Cloud"
                    options={{
                        tabBarItemStyle: styles.iconspacing,
                        tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => <Text style={[{ color: focused ? COLORS.light_green : COLORS.white }, styles.lable]}>Cloud</Text>,
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                            return (<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} color={focused ? COLORS.light_green : COLORS.white} size={20} />)
                        },
                    }} component={WebViewComponent} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Shop"
                    options={{
                        tabBarItemStyle: styles.iconspacing,
                        tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => <Text style={[{ color: focused ? COLORS.light_green : COLORS.white }, styles.lable]}>Shop</Text>,
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                            return (<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCartShopping} color={focused ? COLORS.light_green : COLORS.white} size={20} />)
                        },
                    }} component={WebViewComponent} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Kontakt"
                    options={{
                        tabBarItemStyle: styles.iconspacing,
                        tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => <Text style={[{ color: focused ? COLORS.light_green : COLORS.white }, styles.lable]}>Kontakt</Text>,
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                            return (<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} color={focused ? COLORS.light_green : COLORS.white} size={20} />)
                        },
                    }} component={WebViewComponent} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Open Externally"
                    options={{
                        tabBarItemStyle: styles.iconspacing,
                        tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => <Text style={[{ color: focused ? COLORS.light_green : COLORS.white, minWidth: 70 }, styles.lable]}>Open Externally</Text>,
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                            return (<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowUpRightFromSquare} color={focused ? COLORS.light_green : COLORS.white} size={20} />)
                        },
                    }} component={WebViewComponent} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

WebViewComponent.tsx

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Linking } from 'react-native';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Loading from '../component/Loading';


function WebViewComponent(): JSX.Element {
    const route: any = useRoute();
    const [routeParams, setRouteParams] = useState<any>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (route?.params) {
            setRouteParams(route?.params)
        }
    }, [route?.params])

    if (!route?.params) {
        return (<Loading />)
    }

    if (routeParams && routeParams?.ExternalRedirection === true) {
        Linking.openURL(routeParams?.RedirectionURL)
    }

    return (
        <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://Example.com' }} style={{ flex: 1 }} />
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#2c3e50',
    },
});

export default WebViewComponent;
```

i want to listen my bottom tab bar press event Which name is "Back" in WebViewComponent
note i want to listen only "Back tab bar" press events not others. because i want to do back in web view page on bottom tab bar press event.